# $http response returning quoted string in previous version, but not in current version

Tags: angularjs

I am upgrading Angular from 1.2.15 to 1.3.14, and seeing some unusual results.
I am using $http to call a URL and get back some text. In 1.2, the result is coming back quoted. In 1.3 there are no quotes in the result.

I am not seeing any documentation for this in the [AngularJS migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration).

The server is SpringMVC returning a proper String:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(propTagStr, HttpStatus.OK);
```

The client call looks like this:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8070/getPropertiesForHistoryId.do?historyid=1";
return $http.get(url).then(function(result) {
     historyCache.setData(result.data);
});
```

When I execute the URL in the browser the response string is indeed quoted. So why is AngularJS 1.3 trimming off those quotes?

Comment: ??? Strings should have quotes, this var url line is invaid! I did'nt get you!

Comment: Sorry, just a transcription error, I corrected it

Comment: Check out the content type from the response and post it!

Comment: it sounds like the information you just provided in the edit is extremely relevant, however you didn't elaborate on that enough to know what the difference might be.

Comment: Header.Accept is application/json, text/plain, */* and as I said the server is returning type String.

Comment: and that string is being treated as json. Doesn't make sense sending strings as json in the first place

Comment: I tried using produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE on the server and             return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: url,
                headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=us-ascii"}
            });
on the client, but I am getting a 406 (Not Acceptable)

Comment: In any case, it is an undocumented change in behavior between Angular 12 and 13

Comment: you added, then removed, a segment of the question where you suggested that this works correctly when calling normally, but exhibits the behavior you are describing when using `$q.all`.  Did that turn out to not be the case?

Comment: That's right, I was mistaken. The behavior was the same outside $q as well. Angular 1.2 and Angular 1.3 are returning different results in both cases